# Is there any way to discard a committed transaction?

Tags: cleos, transactions, eosjs, deferred-transactions

I always have this doubt whenever i push a transcation. Is there any way to cancel a committed transaction before it's verifed by the block producers?

Comment: No. Except it is a deferred Tx.

Comment: deferred transactions can be cancelled.

Comment: explain with code @Muhzin

Answer (score 2):

You can delay a transaction.

While using cleos just add

`--delay-sec [seconds to delay]`

and probably `cleos wallet lock` will stop cleos from pushing the transaction as long as you're within the delay but that doesn't really sound like a way one should go.